# AWS serverless with nextjs Only deploy s3 and cloudFront

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, next.js, aws-serverless

I have a question about AWS serverless with Nextjs.

I would like ask if I can deploy my build file(.next) only to s3 and coludFront when I trigger `serverless`

It seems like each time I deploy my application with below script, serverless do more things than I would like to do(only build and upload s3 and cloud front)

Thank you for advance. Have a good day:)

Here is my deploy script

```
#
# GitHub Action for Serverless NextJS production environment
#
name: Deploy prod-nextjs-starter

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
jobs:
  deploy-prod:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ap-northeast-2

      - uses: canastro/copy-file-action@master
        with:
          source: "serverless-prod.yml"
          target: "serverless.yml"

      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2-beta
        with:
          node-version: "14"

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Generate Environment Variables File for Production
        run: |
          echo "NEXT_PUBLIC_UNSPLASH_API_KEY=$NEXT_PUBLIC_UNSPLASH_API_KEY" >> .env
        env:
          NEXT_PUBLIC_UNSPLASH_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_UNSPLASH_API_KEY }}

      - name: Serverless AWS authentication
        run: npx serverless --component=serverless-next config credentials --provider aws --key ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }} --secret ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}

      - name: Download `.serverless` state from S3
        run: aws s3 sync s3://nextjs-starter-serverless-state-bucket/nextjs-starter/prod/.serverless .serverless --delete

      - name: Deploy to AWS
        run: npm run deploy

      - name: Upload `.serverless` state to S3
        run: aws s3 sync .serverless s3://nextjs-starter-serverless-state-bucket/nextjs-starter/prod/.serverless --delete
```

Comment: You can't deploy the `.next` app to only CloudFront and s3 because you'd be missing the SSR infrastructure.  You can deploy an SSG site (`next export`) to CloudFront and S3. If you deploy your static site to one of the templates, I believe it will still work, but you'd have extra resources provisioned.  If you want to deploy a purely static site, there are a lot of templates and guides like https://www.alexhyett.com/terraform-s3-static-website-hosting

Comment: Thank you for your answer! @SeanW.
The reason I would like to deploy .next app to only CloudFront and s3 is deploy time. my example app (only 2page nextjs app) take 6~8 min to deploy with serverless..! Is this deploy time normal for nextjs app? otherwise Could you give me advise to reduce deploy time?

Comment: The video would be helpful. thank you so much! your deploy workflow ( S3 and ClouldFront invalidate) still can use nextjs SSR?